# How to determine whether a device is handset or tablet using findFragmentById() method?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a situation, where I'm checking whether a device is a handset or tablet. I have 1 activity and 2 fragments. I want to send the data from the first fragment to the 2nd fragment through activity. The code works in the tablet. But when i run it in the handset, it gives "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003f (com.example.fruitsappfragmentdemo:id/fragment_container2) for fragment DetailFragment".

```
    @Override
        public void clickItem(int position) {

            DetailFragment fragment = (DetailFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container2);

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("pos", position);
            if (fragment == null || fragment.getShownIndex()!=position) {
                DetailFragment detail=new DetailFragment();
                detail.setArguments(bundle);
                replaceNewFragment(detail);

            } else {

                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                replaceFragment(fragment);

            }
}
```

What is the problem. Y its not working in handset. How to solve this problem?

Comment: In what layout & folder is `R.id.fragment_container2` contained?

Comment: in  layout-large folder

Comment: I know its not able to identify that id..But how to overcome this problem?